# Overide delete(-rm) event to move to(-mv) folder

Tags: shell-script, files, delete, keyboard-event

I have a trouble with deleting files on my company's LAN network. I have 5x5TB shared disks where data is stored. About 20 clients (PC Users) have access to the disks. The big problem is when someone delete something they didn't want to remove or delete some one else job. Because, shared disks don't have a recycle bin (Trash) folder and deleting is pernament (or with recovery software...).

We have 20 Windows PCs (cliet Users) and one Linux server(main) with those shared disks. I was wondering if I could somehow run a script that would move files to the Trash instead of deleting them. Because when User on Windows PC access to shared disk on server and delete something, there is no recycle bin to easy recover that.

It is possible to trigger "move to" event at delete event?

Comment: XY problem - it'd make *way* more sense to limit users access. Confidentiality, integrity, availability!

Comment: I know that user access control will solve this problem, but this solution require at least one privilaged user to delete unnecessary files.

Comment: And your current situation (any user is privileged) is better? I'd say this is irresponsible. You are only thinking about deletion - what if a user decides to rename everything to their liking? Or creates backups of files he or she is not allowed to? This situation sounds like an IT nightmare.

Comment: Is an hourly backup something that you have or that you are considering? E.g. using some real backup software like `restic`...

Comment: @Panki You are right... At all. It is an our nightmare :D :D :D when there is no other option I will do it via permissions, but I would like to know if it can be solved with a script

Comment: @Kusalananda I was wondering if Incremental Backup will be worth to try

Comment: @Sahasrar Um, yes? It looks like you're managing a system for more people than just for yourself, so I would assume a backup policy of _any kind_ would be in order.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume your linux server is sharing the disks via samba.  If that's the case, have you looked at vfs_recycle (https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/vfs_recycle.8.html) ?

It creates a recycle directory at the share level... independent of individual users.

Comment: Thanks... May be this is way... I will try this